# How to get input checkbox (change) event value on and off?

Tags: angular, typescript

The result always coming as "on". I want to make it get two results when on and off.

```html
  <label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary switch-success">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="isChangeLimitAccessToggle($event.target.value)" id="ifLimitAccess" class="switch-input">
    <!-- [attr.disabled]="switchDisable?'':null"  [checked]="switchEnable" -->
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span>
    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
  </label>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use **checked** attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="isChangeLimitAccessToggle($event.target.checked ? 'on' : 'off')" id="ifLimitAccess" class="switch-input">
```

Comment: If someone uses mat-checkbox instead of input, then use $event.checked, since there is no attribute target in that case.

Comment: won't work with strict checks.

Comment: That's true - the types are somehow not correct. Anyone know how to strictly type that?

Answer (score 2):

Add the [(ngModel)] directive to your input:

```
<label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary switch-success">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue"(change)="isChangeLimitAccessToggle(checkboxValue)" id="ifLimitAccess" class="switch-input">
<!-- [attr.disabled]="switchDisable?'':null"  [checked]="switchEnable" -->
<span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span>
<span class="switch-handle"></span>
```

Comment: this one also if we are  using formControlName

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" value = "1"(change)="isChangeLimitAccessToggle($event.target.value)"  class="switch-input">
```

you can pass value in input tag and when you will click on check box then you get 1 value so it will work for you.